# Azure App service Keeps pulling docker image from docker hub

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I have a azure app service to host a docker image from out Azure Container Registry.

The full process is as follow:

- Run Pipeline
- Run Release pipeline
- Azure app pulls the latest release from azure container registry

But what happen is that after Each realise, for some reason, the app service tries to pull the image from `Docker Hub`instead of pulling from azure Container Registry.

Can somebody help to understand where is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, I can guess the problem you made, you must set the image with the tag as, for example, `nginx:latest`. But if you push the image in the ACR and need to pull it from the ACR, you must set the image with the tag as `myacr.azurecr.io/nginx:latest`. In addition, you also need to configure the credential for your ACR.

Comment: Indeed, azure portal wasn't saving my configurations and kept in memory the old one. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: not work for me ; i set XXXXXX.azurecr.io/XXXXXXXXX:tag in release pipeline , but still have the same problem

Comment: @QuentinMerlin Create a new question with more details of your problem. It's better to figure out the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159823/cannot-pull-image-in-webapp-from-acr-with-private-endpoint-enabled

Comment: @QuentinMerlin OK, I'll take a look.